# How to check and calculate the complete size of oracle database, tablespaces, schemas, objects, recycle bin and more?

Tags: sql, oracle

This question answer is already available in segments over the internet with a more informative title.
Aspirants mostly looking for a different type of size accumulation:

- Complete Size of Database on a physical disk.
- Actual space used by complete DB, all schemas, specific user, objects, and quota space.
- Space occupied by dba_recyclebin for all DB and users
- Size of physical and temporary tablespace with calculated details

And we will keep on update this Solution for more helpful, thank!

Answer (score 1):

Here are a useful set of SQL statements:

**# Complete Size of Database on a physical disk (unless you are using ASM).**

```
select sum(bytes / (1024*1024)) "DB Size in MB" from dba_data_files;
select sum(bytes / (1024*1024*1024)) "Size in GB" from dba_data_files;
select sum(bytes / (1024*1024*1024)) "Size in GB" from dba_temp_files;
select (select sum(bytes)/1024/1024/1024 from dba_data_files) + (select sum(bytes)/1024/1024/1024 from dba_temp_files) "Size in GB" from dual;
```

**# Actual space used by complete DB, all schemas, specific user, objects and quota space.**

```
select sum(bytes)/1024/1024/1024 "Size in GB" from dba_segments;
select owner, sum(bytes)/1024/1024 "Size in MB" from dba_segments group  by owner;
select owner, sum(bytes)/1024/1024 "Size in MB" from dba_segments where owner='SYSMAN' group  by owner;
select segment_name, segment_type, bytes/1024/1024 "Size in MB" from dba_segments where segment_type='MATERIALIZED VIEW' and segment_name='MPC_TIME_WRITING_ALL_MV';
--Size quota space
select username, tablespace_name, sum(bytes)/1024/1024 "Size in MB" from dba_ts_quotas where username in ('SYSMAN') group by username, tablespace_name;
```

**# Space occupied by dba_recyclebin for all DB and users**

```
--Fyi,  SHOW PARAMETERS db_block_size
--      1 block = 512 bytes         
select owner, type, count(*) from dba_recyclebin group by owner, type;  
select owner, (sum(space)*512)/1024/1024 "Size in MB" from dba_recyclebin group by owner order by sum(space);
select owner, (sum(space)*512)/1024/1024 "Size in MB" from dba_recyclebin where owner='SYSMAN' group by owner order by sum(space);
```

**# Size of physical and temporary tablespace with calculated details**

```
--Physical tablespace
SELECT tablespace_name, SUM(bytes)/1024/1024 "Used in MB", SUM(maxbytes)/1024/1024 "Max in MB" FROM dba_data_files GROUP BY tablespace_name;
SELECT tablespace_name, SUM(bytes)/1024/1024 "Used in MB", SUM(maxbytes)/1024/1024 "Max in MB" FROM dba_data_files WHERE tablespace_name='SYSAUX' GROUP BY tablespace_name;

--Temporary tablespace
SELECT tablespace_name, SUM(bytes)/1024/1024 "Used in MB", SUM(maxbytes)/1024/1024 "Max in MB" FROM dba_temp_files GROUP BY tablespace_name;
SELECT tablespace_name, SUM(bytes)/1024/1024 "Used in MB", SUM(maxbytes)/1024/1024 "Max in MB" FROM dba_temp_files WHERE tablespace_name='SYS_TEMP' GROUP BY tablespace_name;

--Calculated details
SELECT df.tablespace_name TABLESPACE, df.total_space TOTAL_SPACE,
fs.free_space FREE_SPACE, df.total_space_mb TOTAL_SPACE_MB,
(df.total_space_mb - fs.free_space_mb) USED_SPACE_MB,
fs.free_space_mb FREE_SPACE_MB,
ROUND(100 * (fs.free_space / df.total_space),2) PCT_FREE
FROM (SELECT tablespace_name, SUM(bytes) TOTAL_SPACE,
   ROUND(SUM(bytes) / 1048576) TOTAL_SPACE_MB
   FROM dba_data_files
   GROUP BY tablespace_name) df,
  (SELECT tablespace_name, SUM(bytes) FREE_SPACE,
    ROUND(SUM(bytes) / 1048576) FREE_SPACE_MB
    FROM dba_free_space
    GROUP BY tablespace_name) fs
WHERE df.tablespace_name = fs.tablespace_name(+)
ORDER BY fs.tablespace_name;
```

The above list of SQL statements are gist to help you achieve your result, You may alter them as per your requirement.

Thanks!